# How detect clicking parse notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I use parse push notification in my app.
When i send message to all device in my dashboard,i cannot get delivery push when use click on notification.
Is there any way to detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a push is sent and received, the proper method is called by ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. You should write your own custom class that overrides the original ParsePushBroadcastReceiver like so.

```
public class CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    //Called when the push notification is opened by the user.
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Opened!");
```

...implement other methods if needed

Specifically, the onPushOpen will be called when the user clicks on the notification.

Also, don't forget to update your manifest for the custom class like so

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And make sure you've called `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("")` where the parameter is the channel you want to subscribe to (leaving it blank subscribes to all I believe ).